# Referenced project dependency is copying from GAC instead of NuGet package folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I'm having a strange issue where I have a Windows Service project (A) that references another project in the solution (B).  The project B has a reference to a nuget package (in this case, protobuf-net); it is correctly referencing the path in the packages folder.  However, when I build the Windows Service project A, the DLL that gets copied is a different version (which is coming from the GAC).

What's the best way to resolve this, and ensure that it's properly copying the dependency.

I tried deleting the associated folder in the packages folder and then rebuilding Project B; this did result in nuget automatically downloading the files again, however I see that the reference in Visual Studio for Project B was updated to an older version in the GAC.  I had to remove the reference in the packages.config file, and then add it again using nuget to get it to update to using the correct path in the packages folder.

Comment: Side note: unless there is some strong reason to have those assemblies in the GAC it may be better to uninstall them from GAC... Usually assemblies distributed via NuGet are expected to be copied along with app and not installed. GAC always take priority in loading assemblies - so if version is not incremented properly copy from the GAC will take over.

Comment: Yeah, not sure why or how that assembly ended in the GAC.  However, the nuget package is referencing v2.0.0 and the GAC has v1.0.0.  Pretty strange and annoying to say the least.

Comment: What's even more weird, is that there is another project (C) that references Project B.. and the build/publish output for it actually includes the correct version of the referenced assembly.  Just this one project seems to be having issues.

Comment: Well, I just setup a publish profile for the service project (A), and guess what... the "Application Files" folder contains the correct version of the assembly.  But build doesn't.

Comment: Any chance you have a binding redirect in your app config for this specific assembly?

Comment: I have the same problem. System.Runtime assembly is copied from GAC, not from package folder where a newer version is. I have binding redirection to the newer version that fails because in app root folder I have old version from GAC.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem and resolved it by setting "Copy Local" to false for the reference to Project B in Project A.

In my case, all of my projects have the same Output path.  I have an EXE (project A) and a DLL (project B).  The DLL has a reference to a Nuget package. When I would compile just the DLL it would copy the referenced Nuget DLL from the packages folder to the output folder.

However, when I compiled the EXE it would overwrite that Nuget DLL with an older version from the GAC.  **Setting "Copy Local" to False fixed it** so that the Nuget DLL only gets copied when the DLL is compiled and not when the EXE is compiled.